# SQL Selecting all data between date ranges when date is stored as nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008, date

I inherited a T-SQL table with `Start_Date` and `End_Date` columns that are `nvarchar` data types. I need to select all the records for a particular day who's start date is before that date but have an end date after that date.

Another wrinkle is that some people are still current and do not have an `end_date`. Sadly, I cannot just convert the data type of the column to a date. I am trying to write this in VBA because

1. my boss understands Excel, and
2. the reports he is doing must be sent as Excel

For example:

```
Name    Start_Date    End_Date
Joe     12/1/2014     6/15/2016
Bob     8/28/2013     6/5/2014
Jon     1/27/2015     12/18/2015
Tim     8/28/2013
```

If my selected date were 8/15/2015, my returned data should be

```
Name    Start_Date    End_Date
Joe     12/1/2014     6/15/2016
Jon     1/27/2015     12/18/2015
Tim     8/28/2013
```

I've tried the following queries, but they return `Run-time error -2147217900 (80040e14) Automation error`

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM INFORMATION 
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, START_DATE, 101) >= '12/1/2015' 
  AND CONVERT(datetime, END_DATE, 101) <= '12/31/2015'

SELECT NAME 
FROM INFORMATION 
WHERE START_DATE >= '12/1/2015'
```

---

Edit:
I am using the following code to construct my query:

```
For intYear = Year(Now()) To 2012 Step -1
    For intMonth = 12 To 1 Step -1
        FirstDayOfMonth = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, 1)
        LastDayOfMonth = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth + 1, 0)
        SQL = "SELECT NAME FROM dbo.INFORMATION " & _
              "WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, START_DATE, 101) <= " & FirstDayOfMonth & " AND " & _
              "CASE END_DATE WHEN '' THEN GETDATE() " & _
              "ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, END_DATE, 101) END >= " & LastDayOfMonth
        Debug.Print SQL
        'Output:
        'SELECT NAME FROM dbo.INFORMATION WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, START_DATE, 101) 
        '<= 12/1/2016 AND CASE END_DATE WHEN '' THEN GETDATE() ELSE 
        'CONVERT(DATETIME, END_DATE, 101) END >= 12/31/2016
        Set rs = cn.Execute(SQL)
    Next intMonth
Next intYear
```

---

Update 2:

I set `SQL` to the literal query rather than dynamically generating it and put in error catching (which I really should have done long ago). I think putting single quotes around the dates will cause it to be a string rather than a date, but I tried it both ways.

```
SQL = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM dbo.INFORMATION " & _
      "WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, START_DATE, 101) <= 12/01/2016 " & _
      "AND CASE END_DATE " & _
      "WHEN '' THEN GETDATE() " & _
      "ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, END_DATE, 101) " & _
      "END >= 12/31/2016"
```

Both with and without single quotes the actual SQL error from SSMS is:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Looking at the data in the table, I can see that some dates are NULL, some are blank, and some are mm/dd/yy (or even m/d/yy). I wanted SQL to do all the heavy lifting, but now I'm trying to determine if it will be tougher to `SELECT *` and deal with it in Excel or engage my boss, his peers, and my grandboss to 'fix' the table.

Comment: In your VBA SQL construction string you might need to add in the single quote characters around the date literals and perhaps use the format function on the date values to ensure the VBA dates are being properly formatted to a 'mm/dd/yyyy' string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch your >= and <=.  Right now you're looking for people with start dates AFTER your target date and end dates BEFORE your target date.  But I assume that's just a typo in your example.

You're on the right track though.  When you say you want to do this in VBA, I'd caution against doing any logic in VBA.  Do all of your filtering in SQL, and just use VBA to call the SQL.  Also, don't forget that you can connect Excel directly to SQL as a data source and skip VBA.

Anyway, your SQL query should look something like this:

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    dbo.INFORMATION
WHERE   CONVERT(DATETIME, Start_Date, 101) <= @targetdate
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, End_Date, 101) >= @targetdate
```

But then you have the case of someone with no end date.  Let's fix it so it all fits in one query.

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    dbo.INFORMATION
WHERE   CONVERT(DATETIME, Start_Date, 101) <= @targetdate
                    AND     CASE End_Date
                              WHEN '' THEN GETDATE()
                              ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, End_Date, 101)
                            END >= @targetdate
```

Here we're using their end date if they have one, and if they don't we're using now.  If your target date could ever be in the future, then you could use an arbitrarily large date instead.

One last item is to make it more readable, using BETWEEN:

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    dbo.INFORMATION
WHERE   @targetdate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, Start_Date, 101)
                    AND     CASE End_Date
                              WHEN '' THEN GETDATE()
                              ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, End_Date, 101)
                            END
```

Comment: Great catch on the `>=` and `<=`... +1 for that! However, I'm still getting the automation error. Please see my edit.

Comment: It's a VBA error, and unfortunately I don't know anything about VBA.  Do you have access to query SQL directly?  I'd suggest confirming the query works through SQL Management Studio, and then changing your VBA code to do something simple like select top 10 Name from Information, and my guess is that you'll get the same error as it's probably unrelated to any particular SQL query.

Comment: Your query would be awesome if my data were cleaner. Any chance you know how I can deal with the variability of the dates?

Comment: Yikes.  Yes, ideally you would fix the data.  An easy way to do this would be to copy it to a new table in the correct format, and selecting from the new table.  You'd still have the old table in case something goes awry.  

Another option is a view on the table, and inside the view you fix the dates with a bunch of case statements (basically if it's mm/dd/yyyy use 101 for the convert, if mm/dd/yy use 1, etc).  See http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/ .  This way your VBA query is simple, and the view is the one-time complex item.

Comment: Interesting tidbit: One of the dates is 9/2/605 (I'm sure it was meant to be 9/2/05 or maybe 06). VBA recognizes that as a valid date and works with it just fine. However, Excel crashes if you try to insert that value into a cell formatted as a date.